# TikZ/PGF: dimension too large even though below \maxdimen

Tags: tikz-pgf, fpu

Why does the following code trigger the error `! Dimension too large.` when compiling it with `pdflatex`, even though the dimension should only be 11in (which is below `\maxdimen`)?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathparse{10in + 1in}
\def\y{\pgfmathresult}
\node at ( 0, \y ) { y-position: \y };
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Basically I want to be able to calculate node positions using PGF's FPU, due to the `\maxdimen` limitation. Expressions like `sqrt(pow(10in, 2) + pow(12in, 2))` don't seem to be possible in TikZ, even tho the actual result is only ~15.6in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result is within TeX dimension limits but you use the value without a unit,  794.96.... is understood as centimeters and it becomes 22K+ pts. So add `pt` after the `\y`

```
\node at ( 0, \y pt ) { y-position: \y };
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, makes sense. Is the result of `\pgfmathresult` always implicitly converted to `pt`, even though inches are used in the calculation?

Comment: @watain Yes, TeX and hence TikZ works with `pt` and internally things are always converted to `pt`.