# How to use the TikZ fpu library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fpu

When I calculate something, sometimes become the interim results to big for the `pgf` system. One can use the `fpu` library. I read about it in the `TikZ & PGF` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (see page 627), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175805/tikz-pgf-dimension-too-large-even-though-below-maxdimen) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal) but I still get this error:

```
Paragraph ended before `\pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat` was complete.
```

What is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}

  %data values:
  \def\RTable{{100,100.391,100.781,101.172,101.562,101.953,102.343,102.733,103.123,103.513,103.903,104.292,104.682,105.071,105.46,105.849,106.238,106.627,107.016,107.405,107.794,108.182,108.57,108.959,109.347,109.735,110.123,110.51,110.898,111.286,111.673,112.06,112.447,112.835,113.221,113.608,113.995,114.382,114.768,115.155,115.541,115.927,116.313,116.699,117.085,117.47,117.856,118.241,118.627,119.012,119.397,119.782,120.167,120.552,120.936,121.321,121.705,122.09,122.474,122.858,123.242,123.626,124.009,124.393,124.777,125.16,125.543,125.926,126.309,126.692,127.075,127.458,127.84,128.223,128.605,128.987,129.37,129.752,130.133,130.515,130.897}}

  %prints the result to the console:
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
  \foreach \i in {0, ..., 80}
    {
     \pgfmathparse{abs(\RTable[\i] - 100 - 3.0897 / 8 * \i)}\i, \pgfmathresult\\
    }
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

\end{document}
```

**Update:**

I'am using a macro from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518297/is-it-possible-to-plot-complicated-functions-with-tikz-datavisualization) (thanks to [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat)). See my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newcommand\pgfmathparseFPU[1]{
                               \begingroup
                                 \pgfkeys{
                                          /pgf/fpu,
                                          /pgf/fpu/output format = fixed
                                         }
                                 \pgfmathparse{#1}
                                 \pgfmathsmuggle
                                 \pgfmathresult
                               \endgroup}

\begin{document}

  %data values:
  \def\UABmValues{{14.9, 15.8, 17.7, 18.3, 19, 20, 21.1, 22.2, 24.3, 26.9, 30.1}}

  %prints the result to the console:
  \foreach[count = \i from 0] \k in {30, 35, ..., 80}
    {
     \pgfmathparseFPU{-25500 / (\UABmValues[\i] / 1000 - 255 / 52) - 5200 - 3.0897 / 8 * \k}\i, \pgfmathresult\\
    }

\end{document}
```

and get still a

```
Paragraph ended before `\pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat` was complete.
```

error. What do am I wrong?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure this can be fixed, as pgfmath is constantly converting back and forth between text, dimen registers and fpu registers (which is why I regard it as a dancing bear).

Comment: Hello everybody! Has no one of the professionals a proposal for a solution?

Comment: Note that `\pgfkeys{pgf/fpu=false}` will not do what it says on the tin unless it has recently been fixed.

Comment: I feel you should ask a new question on this since you got already a nice answer. `\foreach[count = \i from 0] \k in {30, 35, ..., 80}
    {
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myval}{\UABmValues[\i]}
     \pgfmathparseFPU{-25500/(\myval/1000-255/52)-5200-3.0897/8*\k}\i, \pgfmathresult\\
    }` works. As of now, `fpu` does not support a couple of things, including integer manipulation, and this kind of list extraction. So you need to extract the entry without `fpu`.

Comment: Hello @Schrödinger's cat, thank you for the hint! I leave the question like it is now and ask an [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521857/tikz-fpu-seems-to-be-inaccurate), because `fpu` seems to be inaccurate. If you have time, so please take a look at it. Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: @Su-47 I think Alain Matthes answer is good. Please note that none of the systems can really compete with a computer algebra system. A radically new version of TeX would be require to *really* lift the internal limitations, but AFAIK there is no plan to ever set up a new TeX. Please also note that IMHO it is better to wait using expl3 until it is in a state where you can be sure that what you wrote will still work in a year from now. Since you seem to be using MatLab, you can always produce the data with this tool and then plot it with pgfplots or datavisualization.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the LaTeX3 FPU:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \clistitem \clist_item:Nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \foreachint \int_step_inline:nnnn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

  %data values:

  \def\RTable{100,100.391,100.781,101.172,101.562,101.953,102.343,102.733,103.123,103.513,103.903,104.292,104.682,105.071,105.46,105.849,106.238,106.627,107.016,107.405,107.794,108.182,108.57,108.959,109.347,109.735,110.123,110.51,110.898,111.286,111.673,112.06,112.447,112.835,113.221,113.608,113.995,114.382,114.768,115.155,115.541,115.927,116.313,116.699,117.085,117.47,117.856,118.241,118.627,119.012,119.397,119.782,120.167,120.552,120.936,121.321,121.705,122.09,122.474,122.858,123.242,123.626,124.009,124.393,124.777,125.16,125.543,125.926,126.309,126.692,127.075,127.458,127.84,128.223,128.605,128.987,129.37,129.752,130.133,130.515,130.897}

  %prints the result to the console:

  \foreachint{1}{1}{81}{%
    #1,
    \fpeval{abs(\clistitem\RTable{#1} - 100 - 3.0897 / 8 * (#1 - 1))}\\
  }

\end{document}
```

(The convention in `expl3` is to index from 1 as this aligns with the most common use case: typesetting. I've therefore indexed the list from one but corrected to index from zero for the equation itself.)

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wright! Thank you for your answer I tested it.
**1.** Of course it works, but the index variable should begin by zero (for my special purpose).
**2.** The results of your answer are different. The correct results should look like a downwards parabola see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348739/is-it-possible-to-use-arrays-in-a-function-of-tikz-datavisualization). Results of your answer looks like a opened upwards parabola. Maybe I do something wrong.
**3.** Anyway I can't use your answer in my question (see the link above).
What do you say?

Comment: @Su-47 I don't know what you mean about 'the link above'

Comment: The link in point 2 probably (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348739/is-it-possible-to-use-arrays-in-a-function-of-tikz-datavisualization).

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wright and @Torbjørn T.! Sorry for the long absence. Thank you for your comments. Torbjørn T. is right I meant [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348739/is-it-possible-to-use-arrays-in-a-function-of-tikz-datavisualization). Now the result is right. But as I said in my last comment, I can't use the above answer to solve my another question (see the link above). If I understand correctly currently there is no way to use arrays and `fpu` together in `TikZ`? Is there an another solution, maybe an another data structures as arrays?