# pgfplotstable's create col/expr does not invoke fpu on constants

Tags: pgfplotstable, fpu

I must admit that I am frequently stumbling over the limited numerical precision issues with pgfplots(table). I am aware that `\pgfset{fpu}` activates the IEEE double precision unit. Moreover, the latest manual (v1.15) states:

> This FPU is also part of PgfplotsTable, and it is activated by default for create col/expr ...

With that being said, please help me understand my questions about the following MWE. Take note of the three different expressions for `create col/expr={abs(...)}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
values
392.50271975
392.5024343
392.5016196
392.5005834
392.4992593
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{table.csv}\myerrortable

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/error/.style={
        create col/expr={
            abs(785/2 )%-\thisrow{values})
            %abs(392.5-\thisrow{values})
        }
    },
}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={error},
    columns/error/.style={
        column name={error},
        fixed,
        precision=8,
    },
    ]\myerrortable
\end{document}
```

1. `abs(785/2 )` = `392.499`: Why are only three digits printed? This does not look like the fpu is used.
2. `abs(785/2 -\thisrow{values})` = `0.00372, ...`: As you see the `values` table contains more precision digits and they are partially used. The error is always in the third digit resulting from the limited precision result of `785/2`. So, why is `785/2` limited to 3 digits, and the `values` to 5?
3. `abs(392. - \thisrow{values})` = `0.00272, ...`: If the correct result for 785/2 is used directly, the output is now correct for the given 5 precision digits. But why only 5 digits? The `values` column contains more and I requested 8. I thought fpu gives full *double* precision?

Comment: I have not accepted Marijn's answer, yet, as I would really like to see an answer to my questions above. Is this a bug in pgfplots(table) or am I doing/understanding something fundamentally wrong? Why are the calculations taking place at two different precision levels?

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can use the `expl3` FPU (see, e.g., [How to use the TikZ fpu library?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348799)).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{filecontents}{table.csv}
values
392.50271975
392.5024343
392.5016196
392.5005834
392.4992593
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{table.csv}\myerrortable
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/error/.style={
        create col/expr={
            \fpeval{abs(785/2-\thisrow{values})}
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={values,error},
    columns/values/.style={column name={value},fixed,precision=8,},
    columns/error/.style={column name={error},fixed,precision=8,},
    ]\myerrortable
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Marijn, for that workaround! This is indeed very useful to get out of my current misery and keep my workflow using pgfplots.