# TikZ fpu seems to be inaccurate

Tags: tikz-pgf, fpu

I'am using a macro from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348799/how-to-use-the-tikz-fpu-library) (thanks to [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat)). See my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newcommand\pgfmathparseFPU[1]{
                               \begingroup
                                 \pgfkeys{
                                          /pgf/fpu,
                                          /pgf/fpu/output format = fixed
                                         }
                                 \pgfmathparse{#1}
                                 \pgfmathsmuggle
                                 \pgfmathresult
                               \endgroup}

\begin{document}

  %data values:
  \def\UABmValues{{14.9, 15.8, 17.7, 18.3, 19, 20, 21.1, 22.2, 24.3, 26.9, 30.1}}

  %prints the result to the console:
  \foreach[count = \i from 0] \k in {30, 35, ..., 80}
    {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\UABmValues}{\UABmValues[\i]}
     \pgfmathparseFPU{-25500 / (\UABmValues / 1000 - 255 / 52) - 5200 - 3.0897 / 8 * \k}\i, \pgfmathresult\\
    }

\end{document}
```

Gives:

1. 4.414001000000000
2. 3.483002000000000
3. 3.652002000000000
4. 2.221002000000000
5. 0.990002
6. 0.159003
7. -0.571997
8. -1.302997000000000
9. -1.033997000000000
10. -0.064996
11. 1.304004000000000

When I do the same, let say, with MATLAB:

```
    UABmValues = [14.9 15.8 17.7 18.3 19 20 21.1 22.2 24.3 26.9 30.1];
    R = 30 : 5 : 80;

    %prints the result to the console:
    for j = 1 : 11

      result = -25500 / (UABmValues(j) / 1000 - 255 / 52) - 5200 - 3.0897 / 8 * R(j);
      fprintf('j=%d, ', j)
      fprintf('%d.\n', result)

    end
```

Than I get following:

1. 4.261621e+00.
2. 3.290914e+00.
3. 3.388431e+00.
4. 2.098301e+00.
5. 9.151911e-01.
6. 5.300458e-02.
7. -7.017887e-01.
8. -1.456052e+00.
9. -1.139024e+00.
10. -2.840543e-01.
11. 1.217927e+00.

The difference is huge.

Why is it so? Any suggestions how to solve it with `fpu`, if at least possible?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: The PGF FPU uses TeX `\dimen` registers for calculations, so it has the same accuracy restrictions. The smallest representable difference in a TeX `\dimen` is `1sp`, which is `0.00002pt` (try `\the\dimexpr1sp\relax`). If you need more accuracy, try the LaTeX3 FPU (loaded by the `xfp` package).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik fp gives good results ... but I agree with you xfp seems to be the good way. Perhaps lua is the better way ?

Comment: @AlainMatthes Yes, `fp` has a higher accuracy than the LaTeX3 FPU. (The latter conforms to the IEEE-754 standard, accurate to 16 significant digits or so). But `xfp` (and Lua, for that matter) is fully expandable, while `fp` is not. I'm not sure about Lua's accuracy. But my job description is to advertise `expl3`, so I had to suggest that ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I agree with you `xfp` is fully expandable. I use `fp` because it was the only solution several years ago.I think you have wit lua  IEEE 754 double precision floating point

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The PGF floating point module *is* inaccurate, as it uses TeX arithmetic, so it doesn't go beyond five decimal digits. It is not meant as an all-purpose floating point arithmetic tool, but just to do typesetting.

Use `xfp`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

%data values:
\def\UABmValues{{14.9, 15.8, 17.7, 18.3, 19, 20, 21.1, 22.2, 24.3, 26.9, 30.1}}

%prints the result to the console:
\foreach[count = \i from 0] \k in {30, 35, ..., 80}
  {
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\UABmValues}{\UABmValues[\i]}
   \i, $\fpeval{-25500 / (\UABmValues / 1000 - 255 / 52) - 5200 - 3.0897 / 8 * \k}$\par
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the first I've heard of the xfp package.  Are there any known side effects (for instance, speed)?

Answer (score 13):

You can try **fp**, **xfp** (see egreg's answer) or **lua**

1) **update : version with lua**

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}
\def\luafun#1#2{
    \directlua{
        x = #1;
        y = #2;
       r=-25500/(x/1000-255/52)-5200-3.0897/8*y
       tex.print(r)}
} 

\begin{document}
\def\UABmValues{{14.9, 15.8, 17.7, 18.3, 19, 20, 21.1, 22.2, 24.3, 26.9, 30.1}}

\foreach[count = \i from 0] \k in {30, 35, ..., 80}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myval}{\UABmValues[\i]}%
\luafun{\myval}{\k}\par
 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

**2) old version with fp**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,fp}
\newcommand\pgfmathparseFP[1]{
   \begingroup
        \FPeval\pgfmathresult{(#1)}
     \pgfmathsmuggle
     \pgfmathresult
   \endgroup
    }

\begin{document}

  %data values:
\def\UABmValues{{14.9, 15.8, 17.7, 18.3, 19, 20, 21.1, 22.2, 24.3, 26.9, 30.1}}

%prints the result to the console:
\foreach[count = \i from 0] \k in {30, 35, ..., 80}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myval}{\UABmValues[\i]}%
\pgfmathparseFP{-25500/(\myval/1000-255/52)-5200-3.0897/8*\k}\i, \pgfmathresult\par
 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the drawback of doing so per default? I mean, pgfmath could be patched like this.

Comment: @OlegLobachev maintenance. The maintainers of Ti*k*Z don't *want* to use `expl3` and have their reasons for doing so.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Balance between speed and precision. pgfmath is used usefully by some libraries and precision is not always as important

Comment: I don't know how to use more digits with lua

Comment: @OlegLobachev One of the reasons is performance. It would essentially double the load time. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=50073288#50073288) for a discussion.

Answer (score 6):

An implementation with the CAS **Sage(math)** and **SageTeX**:

[image]

**I use [arara: sagetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520683/arara-sage-a-sagemath-rule-for-arara) for compiling.**

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: sagetex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{sagetex, amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\newcommand\pgfmathparseFPU[1]{
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{
 /pgf/fpu,
/pgf/fpu/output format = fixed
}
\pgfmathparse{#1}
\pgfmathsmuggle
\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
%data values:
\def\UABmValues{{14.9, 15.8, 17.7, 18.3, 19, 20, 21.1, 22.2, 24.3, 26.9, 30.1}}

\section{pgfmath}
\foreach[count = \i from 0] \k in {30, 35, ..., 80}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\UABmValues}{\UABmValues[\i]}
\pgfmathparseFPU{-25500 / (\UABmValues / 1000 - 255 / 52) - 5200 - 3.0897 / 8 * \k}\noindent\i, \UABmValues, \pgfmathresult \\
}

\section{SageTeX}
\subsection{Sage-Output}
$\sagestr{MyOut}$

\subsection{From sageblock or sagesilent}
\begin{sageblock}
Val = ([14.9, 15.8, 17.7, 18.3, 19, 20, 21.1, 22.2, 24.3, 26.9, 30.1])
## Test:
#print Val[1]
#print len(Val)

# Function
f(x,y) = -25500/(x/1000 - 255/52) -5200 -3.0897/8 *(30+5*y)

# Short Output
#for i in range (len(Val)): print i,',',float(Val[i]),',', f(Val[i],i)

# Better Output    
data = [(i,  float(Val[i]), f(Val[i],i)) for i in range(len(Val))] 
data_str = [',   '.join(map(str, t)) for t in data] 
data_str = '\n'.join(data_str) 

MyOut = latex(data_str)
#print data_str
\end{sageblock}
\end{document}
```