# How to draw a hysteresis loop with TikZ datavisualization?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization, fpu

Sorry for my incorrect english.

I have modified the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275192/hysteresis-loop) to adapt it for the `TikZ datavisualization`. Here is the adapted code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = {clean, end labels},
                       all axes = {ticks and grid = {major at = 0}},
                       x axis = {label = $\frac{H}{\si{\A\per\m}}$},
                       y axis = {label = $\frac{B(H)}{\si{\tesla}}$},
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {left, right}
                      ]
    data[set = left] {
      var x : interval [-7 : 7];
      func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * \value x - 1.5)) - 2.5;
    }
    data[set = right] {
      var x : interval [-7 : 7];
      func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * \value x + 1.5)) - 2.5;
    }
    %accents important points
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = {(-1.5 / 1.7)}, y = 0) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [left, font = \footnotesize] {$H_C$};
    }
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = 0, y = 1.59) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [left, font=\footnotesize] {$B_R$};
    }
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = 7, y = 2.5) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [above, font=\footnotesize] {$B_S$};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I get many of this errors:

> ! Dimension too large.
>   `\pgfmath@iterate` ...`\pgfmath@xa \ifdim \pgfmath@x`

One can use the `TikZ fpu` like did [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/pgfplots-and-calculations-without-fpu-dimension-too-large-with-fpu-illegal), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33082/how-can-i-avoid-the-dimension-too-large-error-when-plotting-in-newer-pgf-versi) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175805/tikz-pgf-dimension-too-large-even-though-below-maxdimen). Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions,fpu}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = {clean, end labels},
                       all axes = {ticks and grid = {major at = 0}},
                       x axis = {label = $\frac{H}{\si{\A\per\m}}$},
                       y axis = {label = $\frac{B(H)}{\si{\tesla}}$},
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {left, right}
                      ]
    data[set = left] {
      var x : interval [-7 : 7];
      \pgfkey{/pgf/fpu, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
      func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * \value x - 1.5)) - 2.5;
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    }
    data[set = right] {
      var x : interval [-7 : 7];
      \pgfkey{/pgf/fpu, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
      func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * \value x + 1.5)) - 2.5;
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    }
    %accents important points
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = {(-1.5 / 1.7)}, y = 0) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [left, font = \footnotesize] {$H_C$};
    }
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = 0, y = 1.59) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [left, font=\footnotesize] {$B_R$};
    }
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = 7, y = 2.5) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [above, font=\footnotesize] {$B_S$};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But than my `pdfLaTeX` compiler of `TeXnicCenter` runs into an endless loop. What do I wrong?

By the way: The decoration lines above looks already the same (only coordinates, alignment and text changes). Is there a way to combine/optimize it.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that when the x-value becomes a "large" negative number, it breaks down. If you change the lower limit of the `left` curve to -6.5, and for the `right` curve to -4.5, it compiles fine here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = {clean, end labels},
                       all axes = {ticks and grid = {major at = 0}},
                       x axis = {label = $\frac{H}{\si{\A\per\m}}$},
                       y axis = {label = $\frac{B(H)}{\si{\tesla}}$},
                       data/format = function,
                       visualize as smooth line/.list = {left, right}
                      ]
    data[set = left] {
      var x : interval [-6.5 : 7];
      func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * \value x - 1.5)) - 2.5;
    }
    data[set = right] {
      var x : interval [-4.5 : 7];
      func y = 5 / (1 + exp(-1.7 * \value x + 1.5)) - 2.5;
    }
    %accents important points
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = {(-1.5 / 1.7)}, y = 0) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [left, font = \footnotesize] {$H_C$};
    }
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = 0, y = 1.59) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [left, font=\footnotesize] {$B_R$};
    }
    info {
      \draw (visualization cs:x = 7, y = 2.5) circle [radius = 1pt]
        node [above, font=\footnotesize] {$B_S$};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.! Sorry for the long absence. Thank you for the answer. But I search for a general solution (for example `fpu`). Because if I change slightly the functions, it is enough to change the factor of `x` (for example if I wish to compare two hysteresis loops on one coordinate system) than I have the same problem as before. What do you say?

Comment: @Su-47 I don't really have anything to say, I'm afraid. I don't have a general solution.

Comment: Hello @Torbjørn T.! Thank you for your comment. No problem! Maybe someone has a solution?

Comment: Hello everybody! Since the question couldn't be answered in general. I try to ask a similar question. Maybe then I have more luck.

Comment: Forgot the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354071/dimension-too-large-errors-by-tikz-datavisualization).